# Unity - Will having more scenes make the game heavier?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a game with 100 levels. Each level has a different form of asset, which means the same type but with different form, can change them programmatically. So I want to ask, which is the best way to make 100 levels, with note I can make it in one scene. But I know that will be more hard and more codes.

I also want to know, will the more scene amount make the game more heavy? Thank you:)

Comment: I would like to see the answers to this question, but you also have another possibility. Levels can stored in a xml or even png format and you would have a scene to load them. Of course this might not suit you, you need to ask yourself if the levels can be coded in a generic way. Else i would say 100 scenes, you need to maintain 100 scenes but have more control.

Comment: Haven't tested something like this but I think that loading a code generated level takes longer than a level designed in editor. I am not sure what kind of levels are you talking about (2D, 3D) but with code generated levels you are losing some of the features. Honestly I would go for code only if the levels are very similar in static assets like environment and only some obstacles or enemies are harder through levels.

Comment: Please provide more info, because everything depends on what you call level. If it is a 2D puzzle game and that the layout of each level can be stored in XML instead of a Unity scene then i'd strongly advise doing a small XML loader for your levels and make a call to that between each level it will be a plus for extensibility. But if it is a level like a map (think cs:go or overwatch) then you should store those in scene files because if you need to edit those it will be a nightmare to do that without an editor. As a side note unity scene files are YAML files, so plain text. Except in binaries

Comment: Think about this : How many elements define the specificity of each level? If many things change between each level then sure use a unity scene, if only the position of a couple of elements change then probably storing ir somewhere could help you for the future.

Comment: Well my game is a puzzle game that has a simple map, and a player. But each level has different map, and the location of player start point is different in each level. It's a 2D game. Thanks for all your responds:)